# Is it a good idea to do ski binding settings yourself?

Tags: skiing

My bindings are already adjusted to my shoes, what is not adjusted yet is the release setting.

From what I can tell, the optimal release setting is fairly simple and depends on height, weight, age and skill.

It also seems, that this setting is adjusted by twisting a single screw on the binding.

Is there a valid reason (besides insurance) to not do this myself? Is there actually more to it, than following tables online?

My binding looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind the release settings are only a recommendation following standard practice. Extreme skiers often set their bindings to the hardest because an accidental release while skiing might be more dangerous and deadly than the skis not releasing during a fall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your settings are mostly personal preference.

Adjusting your DIN settings is not a complicated procedure. It's not uncommon for ski resorts to provide public benches with screwdrivers chained to them so people can adjust their bindings on the hill. I've been adjusting my own settings since I was a child.

There's no shortage of charts, youtube videos, etc. online showing you how to set your bindings:

[image]

The settings are there to help you prevent injury. If you're a novice skier you want your skis to pop off easy so you don't break a leg, so you need lower settings. When you get more advanced, you don't want your skis popping off while you're skiing hard or fast, so you need higher settings.

If you don't know how to set your bindings, start with a low number, or find a range that matches your abilities from a chart like the one above. Each time your skis pop off while skiing within your abilities go up a number or two at a time until they stop popping off so easy. If you want to geek out and figure out what your perfect number should be, there are [many resources](http://www.dincalculator.com/#/) to help you figure that out.

Comment: Does my binding look like it's din? I. Bought it in Austria.

Comment: DIN is not a type of binding, but a standard setting of pretty much all bindings. Yes, you can adjust it yourself, but you should know what number you want. The above table gives a pretty wide range, not sure how useful it is.

Comment: @aprilrain I think the table above is very useful for beginners. It illustrates that they don't have to be exact, and that they don't need to be so hung up on their settings in order to go out and ski.

Comment: @user1721135 DIN stands for *Deutsches Institut für Normung*, on ski bindings it's the standardization for release settings.

Comment: @ShemSeger I am not conviced about this, e.g. the category I am looking at has suggested DIN settings between 3 to 12. This spans the entire possible range of the bindings I have. So that gives me close to 0 information about what setting I should actually use.

Comment: You might try this calculator: https://www.skatepro.com/en-us/a114.htm. The result I get is more or less the same as one that was suggested at the shop for me.

Comment: @aprilrain Or it's indicating that you made the perfect choice in your selection of bindings ;) You are right that it's very broad range though, but if anything it illustrates that you have a lot of flexibility. Given the scale above I'd just aim for the middle of the range.

Comment: @aprilrain that's pretty handy!

Answer (score 3):

I was doing ski patrol at a local low level hill.  As skiing the hill is not very challenging.  One fellow patroller suggested decreasing the tension in my bindings.

By doing this, and popping a binding now and then by accident, you become much more aware of your balance and where your weight is.  This turned a low country boring hill into a medium challenge.  I was eventually skiing with DIN 2.

This can also be a benefit if you are skiing with someone who is new, so that you are challenged by slopes that they are challenged by.

My rules now are:

Have your bindings at the lightest setting you can consistently get away with.  Too tight, and you risk injury.  Pre-mature release is just a garage sale most of the time.

I carry a stubby screwdriver of the size to adjust my bindings on the fly.

Comment: Thats another perspecitve, I wasn't thinking about! For the record, I ended up setting my bindings to 7.5 (or maybe it was 8). I did get one faulty release while trying to ski uphill, and one time I fell and they released perfectly, without twisting my legs at all or hurting me, while I tumbled down the slope. I think Id rather not risk too low settings, just so I can improve my form. I did ski with the default settings, which are around 2 and didn't have any releases.

Comment: You can get odd torqueings that interfer with release.  The toe piece releases sideways.  If you are falling back and twisting, the extra lift on the toe can make the mechanism bind some.  Jumping from 2 to 7.5 seems rather extreme.

Comment: According to tables a 2 is way too low for me.